# How to install python-setuptools on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, software-installation, python, yum, repository

On the [understanding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/610783/101935) that both `python-setuptools` and `python-devel` packages are [required](https://github.com/frappe/bench#setup) by `bench` for a scripted install:

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ sudo yum install -y python-setuptools python-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 0:45:02 ago on Wed 23 Sep 2020 05:36:16 AM PDT.
No match for argument: python-setuptools
No match for argument: python-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: python-setuptools python-devel
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ uname -a
Linux rolly 4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 14:37:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core) 
Release:    8.2.2004
Codename:   Core
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

Almost certainly both packages exist for `CentOS` 8 if they existed for `CentOS` 7, although they might've been moved around or renamed.  Possibly I would need to add a repo?

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ yum repolist
repo id                                        repo name
AppStream                                      CentOS-8 - AppStream
BaseOS                                         CentOS-8 - Base
PowerTools                                     CentOS-8 - PowerTools
docker-ce-stable                               Docker CE Stable - x86_64
epel                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
extras                                         CentOS-8 - Extras
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

Although they seem mainstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify either python2 or python3... As `yum install python3-setuptools` or `yum install python2-setuptools`